# Inequality of Partial Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

For a given $\theta < 1$, and $N$ a positive integer, I am trying to find an $x > 0$ (preferably the smallest such $x$) such that the following inequality holds:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{x^k}{k!} \leq \theta e^{x}$$

In my application, even $N$ is an integer function of $x$, i.e. $N = N(x)$, but for simplicity sake, let's assume $N$ is given for now.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading

Fred